# SQL query for rows having one value repeated in more then one column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, duplicates

I have table like:

[image]

I wanted to get all DeviceID which have key=1 more then 1 time. Like device ID= 3 have two rows with key=1, same as 4. What is the query to get that result?

I tried a lot but couldn't find any solution. It seems not possible with `group by` and `having` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the `DeviceIds` with more than one row:

```
select deviceid
from yourtable
where key = 1
group by deviceid
having count(key) > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/275d5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DeviceID
FROM YourTable 
WHERE key = 1
GROUP BY DeviceID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
 **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/750b9/13)**

```
SELECT DevID
FROM Devices
WHERE KeyID = 1
GROUP BY DevID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```